# Chartjs Doughnut cutout option not working

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have upgraded my chartjs and ng2-charts from 2-* to latest version. After updating the packages faced some issues in the properties and fixed those issues. But in the Doughtnut chart, cutout option is not working. As per documentation, I was trying both pixels and percentage.

Here is the sample code

`Chart Js Version - ^4.1.2 Ng2 Charts Version -  ^4.1.1`

```
chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
      },
      y: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    cutout: '94%',
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
```

Here is the error

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cutout' does not exist in type '_DeepPartialObject<CoreChartOptions<keyof ChartTypeRegistry> & ElementChartOptions<keyof ChartTypeRegistry> & PluginChartOptions<...> & DatasetChartOptions<...> & ScaleChartOptions<...>>'.
```

I am not able to find the actual issue. Could anyone help to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NG2-Charts - How to change cutout width for doughnut chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147554/ng2-charts-how-to-change-cutout-width-for-doughnut-chart)

Answer (score 0):

[`cutout`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#config-options) is a property of a `dataset`. It can be set per dataset...

```
{
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      cutout:'40%'
      ...
    },
    {
      cutout:'90%'
      ...
    }]
  }
}
```

...or (as you seem to want to do) for all datasets in the chart:

```
{
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    datasets: {
      doughnut: {
        cutout:'90%'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
chartOptions: ChartOptions<'doughnut'> = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: false,
      },
      y: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    cutout: '94%',
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
```