# NG2-Charts - How to change cutout width for doughnut chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular14

I am working on a corporate project using Angular 14, ChartJS (4.1.2), and NG2-Charts (4.1.1). and I am having some trouble when trying to change the width of the doughnut chart. I show a picture of what I have now:

[image: Chart what I have]

And this is what I am supposed to do:

[image: Chart I want]

At this moment I do not need to put text inside the chart, I just want to reduce the size of the chart, so the text inside fits well.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797862/how-to-set-cutout-on-doughnut-chart-using-ng2-charts) answer, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014123/how-to-vary-the-thickness-of-doughnut-chart-using-chartjs) one, but none of these work and I do not know why.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<canvas baseChart class="chart" 
        style="height: 15vh; max-height: 15vh" 
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [type]="doughnutChartType" 
        [options]="doughnutChartOptions">
</canvas>
```

And the TS code:

```
public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
public doughnutChartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
  labels: this.doughnutChartLabels,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [600, 400, 200],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#AAAAAA',
        '#BBBBBB',
        '#CCCCCC',
      ],
    },
  ],
};
public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
public doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    datalabels: {
      anchor: 'end',
      align: 'end'
    },
  }
};
```

When I try to add this `<'doughnut'>` to my chart options, it breaks the type, and when I remove the type from the HTML, it becomes a bar chart, so I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides changing the `doughnutChartOptions` type as `ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options']`, you also need to change the `doughnutChartType` as `ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['type']` type.

```
public doughnutChartType: ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['type'] = 'doughnut';
public doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options'] = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    datalabels: {
      anchor: 'end',
      align: 'end',
    },
  },
  cutout: '90%',
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nysjrm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yeah, that definitely worked, I shouldve think about that tbh. Thanyou

Answer (score 1):

Normally adding `<'doughnut'>` shouldn't break your code. [I found a similar issue in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797862/how-to-set-cutout-on-doughnut-chart-using-ng2-charts). Try changing either the ng2-charts or the chartJS version in your app.

Here's an example:

```js
public ChartOptions: ChartOptions<'doughnut'> = {
  options: {
    cutout: "99%"
  }
};
```